# From MS Excel VBA, create a Standard Module in MS Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, module

From VBA in Excel (2013), I need to create a standard module in a MS Access (2013) database.  I am open to any and all ideas - Thanks!

Comment: can you share your own first?

Comment: When you say "can you share your own first", I assume you are talking about my ideas to solve this, correct?  If so, I have played with DAO, but haven't made progress.  I have also thought about having a template database with the modlues that I would then do a docmd.CopyObject, but I haven't made progress there either.

Comment: yes, this isn't a code writing service, people will only assist.

Comment: VBA Extensibility you'll need.

Comment: Nathan_Sav, just looking for ideas :)   Another idea I am looking at is DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdNewObjectModule

Comment: there will be a few ways, importing an empty one to, you'll need to load Access library to use it's libraries

Comment: Nathan_Sav: Yes, I had that (Access) reference library and was going through the Object Library looking for ideas.

Comment: look into `VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)`

Comment: AS @Brad says, and I mentioned earlier, use Extensibility to add the code, you can also add the lines of code if you desire.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have it working, but I am sure there are aspects that could/should be done differently. As a reminder, the code below is in MS Excel.  Here is the code:

```
'REQUIRES: MS Access 12.0 Object Library 
Dim ObjAccess As Access.Application 
Dim strPath As String 
strPath = "C:\Temp\MyDB_DEV_1.MDB" 
Set ObjAccess = New Access.Application 
With ObjAccess 
    .OpenCurrentDatabase strPath, True 
    .DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdNewObjectModule 
    .DoCmd.Save acModule, "Module1" 
    .DoCmd.Rename "MyCodedModule", acModule, "Module1" 
    .CloseCurrentDatabase 
    .Quit 
End With 
Set ObjAccess = Nothing`
```

Answer (score 0):

The natural evolution of the previous solution is to want to add code to the new module.  I decided to take an alternate route and "import" an existing standard module into the remote MS Access db.  A final step in the evolution is to remotely run a procedure that is within the standard module that was imported into the remote db.  Again, this code is located in Excel VBA.  The code that accomplishes these two tasks are as follows:

```
'FROM EXCEL, REMOTELY INSTRUCT A MS ACCESS db   
'IMPORTS .BAS FILE INTO db
'EXECUTE THE 'RoutineWithinModule1' THAT IS WITHIN MODULE1 OF THE REMOTE db

Dim appAccess As Access.Application
Set appAccess = New Access.Application

With appAccess
    .OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Temp\MyDB_DEV_1.mdb"
    .VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import "C:\Module1.bas"
    .DoCmd.Save acModule, "Module1"
    .Run "RoutineWithinModule1"
    .CloseCurrentDatabase
    .Quit
End With

Set appAccess = Nothing
```